# reset OnDemandGrid dGrid after applying query

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I can set query  for the `OnDemandGrid` after loading JSON from server  and it filters locally the grid for me without sending any request to server

```
gridPol.set("query", PostID: '339635');
gridPol.refresh()
```

I alos want to add a function  to reset grid to the  fist  state
Is there any option?

Answer (score 0):

It was  so easy

if  set  `null`  in query then grid  changes to first step

```
gridPol.set("query", null);
gridPol.refresh()
```